# Why does blood pressure drop when blood vessels rupture?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation, biology

Some people say that because the flow is large, the pressure is low. Is that right? Why does the pressure drop when the flow rate is high?

Comment: If I have a water sprinkler being driven by water pressure in a hose, and I cut the hose, the water pressure in the hose drops - resulting in a high flow rate at the rupture - and the sprinkler stops working because lack of water pressure. I would argue the rupture caused the low pressure - then the large flow rate occured at the rupture.

Comment: Using a living body makes this difficult, because a standard homeostatic mechanism says – "vessel ruptured? Shut down the blood pressure to minimise leakage!". It's called the vagus reflex and some people get it if a needle pierces a blood vessel for about 50 seconds, *even if nothing leaks out*. So there is more than just physics here, there is biology.

Answer (score 1):

You can have high pressure and a high flow rate...

The pressure needs to be sufficient to overcome the losses in a system.

If a pipe or vessel ruptures then the losses are reduced and the velocity will increase, while the pressure reduces.